# default selected value is not comming in dropdown in angular

Tags: angular

I want to know why the selected value is not coming in the dropdown value?
below is my code :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="stExamSelected" (change)="StudentfilterSelected('exam',$event.target.value)" class="form-control">
   <option [ngValue]="" selected>All Exam</option>
   <option *ngFor="let exam of filteredStudentExamsList | async" [ngValue]="exam"> 
   {{exam.examName}}</option>
```

here, All Exam is not selecting by default, can anyone tell why it is happening and what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[ngValue]` expects a property, to give it a string you need both quotes `[ngValue]="''"`

`value=""` works as well.

`selected` is unnecessary since you have the dropdown bound to `stExamSelected`. Just initialize this property as an empty string and it will select that option.

```js
stExamSelected = '';
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="stExamSelected" (change)="StudentfilterSelected('exam',$event.target.value)" class="form-control">
   <option value="">All Exam</option>
   <option *ngFor="let exam of filteredStudentExamsList | async" [ngValue]="exam"> 
   {{exam.examName}}</option>
```